# Add field to bibliography style

Tags: bibtex, custom-bib

I have generated a style using `latex makebst`. It works perfectly, except that I want to add a 'collaboration' field to my entries, to be shown in parenthesis imediately after the authors. There wasn't an option to do that when building the file, how would I edit the .bst to get this effect?

Note: I am not using biblatex, I am using latex and bibtex.

Comment: Just use the `note` field, it is a standard field. However, the note will not be immediately after the authors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options: either use the `note` field, as it is a standard field. However, the note will not immediately follow the authors.

Since you are using `makebst` there is an even better option: when you are asked for "ADDITIONAL REVTeX DATA FIELDS:", answer with "r" (or manipulate the `dbj` file by hand). This triggers the switches `revdata,eprint,url,url-blk`. You get those REVTeX fields, including `collaboration`, and the content of the `collaboration` field will be printed after the authors, in parentheses.