# Include call number for books in reference

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies

University textbooks are very expensive so that most of us need go to library to find the books listed in a reference. Hence, I would like to include call numbers (e.g., QA278.2.D38 2013) in my reference list so that people do not need to look that up themselves. Is there an easy way to do this in LaTeX, please? Thank you!

Comment: Look here for a quick solution http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87687/add-field-to-bibliography-style

Comment: The `note` field?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what bibliography system you use? Do you use BIbTeX (`.bst` styles), `biblatex` or another system? You can have a look at this question [where we discuss a new "price" field (which can be adapted to your situation quite easily)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/150393/35864).

Comment: The [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) states that `biblatex` already has a `library` field for call numbers. No standard style prints this information by default though. So the only thing you would have to do is enable printing of that field, e.g. by `\newbibmacro*{addendum+pubstate}{%
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{pubstate}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{library}}` (modulo line breaks)

Comment: @egreg Thanks. note field is quite easy and flexible to use.

Comment: @moewe Could you add an answer? I think it's a very interesting feature. Just add at the start that with standard BibTeX tools the only way is with the `note` field.

Comment: @egreg With pleasure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a standard BibTeX environment the easiest solution is the `note` field, virtually all styles support this field and it is the place stuff goes if there is no field better suited.

You can also go down this route if you use `biblatex`, but `biblatex` has a `library` field.
This field is not enabled in the standard styles, though, but with a few lines of code we can make it work.

```
\renewbibmacro*{addendum+pubstate}{%
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{pubstate}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{library}}
```

This is a copy of the "standard" `addendum+pubstate` macro present in all standard drivers with a directive to also print the `library` field at the end.